# eBay CompleteSale API giving error in response

Tags: ebay-api

I am using the following xml for eBay CompleteSale API call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CompleteSaleRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>$auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ItemID>$itemId</ItemID>
<TransactionID>$transId</TransactionID>
<FeedbackInfo>
<CommentText> string </CommentText>
<CommentType>Positive</CommentType>
<TargetUser></TargetUser>
</FeedbackInfo>
<Shipped>1</Shipped>
<Paid>1</Paid>
<ListingType>Half</ListingType>
<Shipment>
    <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
      <ShipmentTrackingNumber>$trackingNo</ShipmentTrackingNumber>
      <ShippingCarrierUsed>$carrier</ShippingCarrierUsed>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
    <ShippedTime>$shippingDate</ShippedTime>
</Shipment>

<ErrorLanguage> string </ErrorLanguage>
<MessageID> string </MessageID>
<Version>889</Version>
<ErrorHandling>BestEffort</ErrorHandling>
<WarningLevel>Low</WarningLevel>
</CompleteSaleRequest>
```

When I run the script, the tracking number gets updated in the eBay correctly, but the response XML gives error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompleteSaleResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2014-10-13T14:39:52.430Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>
  <CorrelationID> string </CorrelationID>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Invalid shipment tracking number or carrier</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>You have entered an incorrect shipment tracking number/carrier.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>2191111</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Tracking numbers invalid</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>The following Tracking Numbers are invalid : TRACKING_NUMBER_VALUE.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>21916897</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
      <Value>TRACKING_NUMBER_VALUE</Value>
    </ErrorParameters>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Internal error to the application.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Internal error to the application.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>10007</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>An error occurred.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>An error number "{0}" occurred while processing your request.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>36</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Version>893</Version>
  <Build>E893_CORE_APIXO_17070435_R1</Build>
</CompleteSaleResponse>
```

Why I am not getting the success in response?

The tracking Number is like: 1Z7X887R0368851221 and carrier is 'UPS'
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide samples of your carrier and trackingNo variables? They don't have to be actual values, but they should match the exact format, including hyphens, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Per [eBay's own dev site:](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/Errors/errorsByCall.html)

> Error 10007 ("Internal error to the application") indicates an error on the eBay server side, not an error in your application.

So you'd probably need to contact eBay about the specific issue, but my assumption is that while eBay will accept in any information into the Carrier and Tracking number fields, the format of the tracking number field must match some other critieria set by the carrier for inserting into another API upstream.

Have you tested the tracking number in UPS's own tracking mechanism? It returns a valid package tracking response?

Also, per the eBay dev site, if you are using UPS Mail Innovations rather than UPS, the carrier name to specifiy is `UPS-MI`.

Comment: Yes, it returns a valid package tracking response, and we can track the package through this tracking number.